# I want to cURL but it redirects to localhost

Tags: curl, localhost

I want to curl my website from my server, but instead of going thru the internet, it goes to localhost.

I have tried changing the Host header, but it doesn't work.

`curl 'website.com/v1/auth?appid=123456&date=20191001123456' -k -v`

It tries to connect directly to 127.0.0.1, and I expect it to go to 'website.com'

edit: Added the logs as pointed out

```
* About to connect() to website.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to website.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /v1/auth?appid=123456&date=20191001123456 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Accept: */*
> Host: website.com
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 03:45:29 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 03:45:30 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Cache-Control: private
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 61
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
<
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: why the frick are you using verbose (`-v`) but not showing us the verbose log? it could hold crucial info about why it's going to localhost. downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your curl is trying to connect to a proxy server instead of connecting to the internet directly.

Check your environment by command env and see if there is any http_proxy.

Also, check if you have some debugging tools like Fiddler or TCPDump or Jmeter setup, as they may create a proxy server.

If you post your curl -v result, I may help to take a look.